# compass command not found after install

Tags: macos, sass, rubygems, osx-elcapitan, compass

Mac OS X El Capitan:

I can't run "compass" in terminal after compass installation.
I knew that i made some mistake when I was installing compass, probably with `sudo`.

My steps:

```
sudo gem install compass
```

If I entering: `compass -v` , returns:

```
command not found: compass
```

If I check my gems: `gem list` , also returns:

```
compass-core (1.0.3) 
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
```

when I run `which -a gem`, I get:

```
/usr/bin/gem
```

my path:

```
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If anybody has any suggestions please help, thanks.

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed? I ran into troubles installing Compass on El Capitan until I had Xcode installed with the terms and conditions accepted.

Comment: check if compass is listed in /usr/local/bin - if not simply the alias is missing

Comment: I had to add `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/` to my path, before the shell was able to find the command.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it with `brew install ruby`, you may also need to re-install compass and sass